# How to calculate percentage based on "a" tags with href attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm struggling getting a percentage value, based on a set of variable number of `a` elements.

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
<a href="#">Friends</a>
<a href="#">Profile</a>
<a href="#">Settings</a>
<a href="#">Logout</a>
...
```

Whenever I finish building a page, I continue to fill other elements' `href` attributes, to create a development progress percentage.

js file looks like this:

```
<script>
var percent = 0;
jQuery.fn.firstElement = function(fn){
    var i = this.length;

    fn.call(this[i], i, this[i]);
}

$('a').each(function(i, obj){
    if ($(obj).attr('href').length > 1){
        $(this).addClass('completed_link');
    }
});

$('a.completed_link').firstElement(function(i){

    /* below part doesn't output what I want to
    so, when I continue to fill attributes, percentage decreases */


    // var full_percentage = 100;
    // percent = parseInt(full_percentage / i);
    // $('.tsk-fill').css('width', percent + '%');


    /* this part shows real percentage for the first 10 elements
    it remains at 100%, on more than 10 */


    for (j=1; j <= i; j++) {
        percent = j*10; 
        $('.tsk-fill').css('width', percent + '%');
    }
}); 
</script>
```

Is there a way to prevent percentage from decreasing and increase it instead?

Comment: You want to fill in the `href`, or other/all, attributes of the `<a>` elements and based on how many elements there are (100% being *all* the `a[href]` elements having attributes completed) you want to have a completion percentage, to work out how many elements are left to complete? Or am I really misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Only the `href` attributes, and yes, you understood correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calculating the percentage in the wrong way, try doing this:

```
var all_links = $('a').length;
percent = parseInt((full_percentage * i) / all_links) // I think you got 10 elements max right?
```

Comment: Before? Yes, but currently I have 12 links, basically, what I want is to set a development progress in "administration" section. I'd like to learn to build a social network myself. Your method works!!! ^^

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it worked for you!

Comment: Alright! However, I'd mark this, and next answer if I could (both of them), because both work!

Answer (score 1):

You can get all of the links where the href does not equal '#' and then all the links.  Use this to divide all the completed (not equal to '#') by the number of all the links and multiply by 100 to get the percentage complete.  Here is a code sample:

```
<a href="google.com">Google</a></br>
<a href="help.com">Help</a></br>
<a href="#">Test2</a></br>
<a href="#">Test3</a></br>
<a href="#">Test4</a></br>

% Complete: <span id="done"></span>

<script>
var done = $('a:not([href="#"])').length;
var all  = $('a').length;

$('#done').append( (done / all) * 100 );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've complete rewritten the code for you, as you've made things way too complicate. I've also created a working example for you.

[Here is my Codepen](http://codepen.io/dschu/pen/ygVbRr)

Also, please note:

> In mathematics, a percentage is a number or ratio expressed as a fraction of 100.

[Percentage on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage)

Having your divisor hard coded to 10 is causing the error.

```js
$menuLinks = $('div.menu > a');
totalPages = $menuLinks.length;
completedPages = totalPages - $menuLinks.filter('[href="#"]').length;
percentage = completedPages / totalPages * 100;

console.log('totalPages', totalPages);
console.log('completedPages', completedPages);
console.log('Completed Percent', percentage);

$('.tsk-fill').css('width', percentage + '%');
```

```css
.bar {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: grey;
}
.tsk-fill {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bar">
  <div class="tsk-fill"></div>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a href="index.php">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Friends</a>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
  <a href="#">Settings</a>
  <a href="#">Profile</a>
</div>
```